# Find maximum and minimum nondiagonal elements of matrix

Tags: arrays, c

I need to find maximum and minimum elements that belong to 4 areas of a matrix which are not parts of the diagonals. I have written code that finds minimum and maximum of the 4 areas that are nondiagonal. However, I need to find those elements separately, which would be 4 minimums and 4 maximums.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j; double mat[100][100], min = 100, max = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%lf", &mat[i][j]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // Numbers that are not diagonal
            if (i != j && i + j != n - 1) {
                printf("%g", mat[i][j]);
                if (mat[i][j] < min)min = mat[i][j];
                if (mat[i][j] > max)max = mat[i][j];
            }
            // Diagonal elements
            else
                printf(" ");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("min %g\n", min);
    printf("max %g\n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `min` and `max` to be arrays. Then write a function that takes `i` and `j` values and returns a `k` where `k` is the quadrant of the matrix that `i` and `j` belong to. Then use `k` for the index into the `min` and `max` arrays.

Comment: for say, min, area[4] where index = `(i<N/2 ? 0:1) + (j<N/2 ? 0:2)`

Comment: @kaylum what would be conditions for the 4 areas, when writing a function that returns k?

Comment: @Déjàvu — I think your formula generates four quadrants with top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right quadrants with sides aligned with the axes.  A different formula/condition is needed to get the quadrants aligned with the diagonals.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh yes, that needs to be rotated 45 degrees :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix must be at least a 3x3 matrix to have off-diagonal elements.  If you have an NxN matrix, then (using `r` for row and `c` for column) the diagonals have `r == c` and `r == N - c - 1` (aka `r + c == N - 1`).  You can simply ignore elements for which either of those conditions is true.

You must place the other elements into one of the four quadrants aligned with the diagonals.  The triangle at the top is the N (north) quadrant; at the bottom is the S (south) quadrant; at the left is the W (west) quadrant; at the right is the E (east) quadrant.

```
 N=5                      N=4
 r\c 0  1  2  3  4        r\c 0  1  2  3
  0  .  N  N  N  .         0  .  N  N  .
  1  W  .  N  .  E         1  W  .  .  E
  2  W  W  .  E  E         2  W  .  .  E
  3  W  .  S  .  E         3  .  S  S  .
  4  .  S  S  S  .
```

The dots represent the diagonals.  In the 5x5 matrix, the W and S elements satisfy `r > c`; the N and E elements satisfy `r < c` (and the elements on the diagonal satisfy `r == c`).  Similarly, the W and N elements satisfy `r + c < N - 1` while the S and E elements satisfy `r + c > N -1` (and the elements on the diagonal satisfy `r + c == N - 1`).  The 4x4 matrix also satisfies these conditions.

You can then use these conditions to classify a given (row, column) pair into one of the four quadrants using an encoding scheme similar to that suggested by [Dèja vu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338904/d%c3%a9j%c3%a0-vu) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858579/find-maximum-and-minimum-nondiagonal-elements-of-matrix#comment125266675_70858579), but adjusted to use different conditions:

```
int quadrant = ((r < c) ? 0 : 1) + ((r + c < N - 1) ? 0 : 2);
```

When `quadrant` is 0, it corresponds to the N quadrant; when it is 1, to the W quadrant; when it is 2, to the E quadrant; when it is 3, to the S quadrant.  Note that this condition assumes that the diagonal elements are not tested.  You might write `assert(r != c && r + c != N - 1);` to ensure that it is not invoked for an element on the diagonals.

You can then compare the element `mat[r][c]` with `min[quadrant]` and `max[quadrant]`, which is the scheme outlined by [kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858579/find-maximum-and-minimum-nondiagonal-elements-of-matrix#comment125266632_70858579).

---

#### Possible code (`matminmax37.c`)

```c
/* SO 7085-8579 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_matrix(const char *tag, size_t n, size_t m, const int matrix[n][m]);

/*
** When quadrant is 0, it corresponds to the N quadrant; when it is 1,
** to the W quadrant; 2, to the E quadrant; when it is 3, to the S
** quadrant.  Note that this condition assumes that the diagonal
** elements are not tested; the assertion ensures that. 
*/
static inline size_t quadrant(size_t r, size_t c, size_t N)
{
    assert(r != c && r + c != N - 1);
    return ((r < c) ? 0 : 1) + ((r + c < N - 1) ? 0 : 2);
}

static void matminmax(size_t n, const int matrix[n][n], int min[4], int max[4])
{
    min[0] = max[0] = matrix[0][1];
    min[1] = max[1] = matrix[1][0];
    min[2] = max[2] = matrix[1][n-1];
    min[3] = max[3] = matrix[n-1][1];
    for (size_t r = 0; r < n; r++)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            if (r == c || r + c == n - 1)
                continue;
            size_t q = quadrant(r, c, n);
            if (matrix[r][c] > max[q])
                max[q] = matrix[r][c];
            if (matrix[r][c] < min[q])
                min[q] = matrix[r][c];
        }
    }
}

static void print_minmax(int min[4], int max[4])
{
    static const char quadname[] = "NWES";
    putchar('\n');
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%c quadrant: min = %4d, max = %4d\n", quadname[i], min[i], max[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Created by: gen_matrix -C -H 999 -L -999 -c 12 -r 12 -i -n mtx1 -w 4 */
    /* Random seed: 0xDB2DC719 */
    const int mtx1[12][12] =
    {
        {  688,  351, -309, -491, -200,  958, -699, -284, -638,  696, -427,   43, },
        { -621,  242,  913, -247, -293,  878,  538,  368, -861,  488, -568,  394, },
        { -646, -813, -943, -417, -697,  551,  325,   11, -234,   18,  348, -229, },
        {  436,  529, -994,  457, -270,  369,  318, -455, -918,  444, -821,  266, },
        {  544,   24,  398, -589, -779,   -2,  932,  810, -915, -591,  877,  865, },
        {   19,  879, -528, -483,  961,  478, -426,  528,  522, -403, -859,  -63, },
        {  830,  103, -662, -894,  -29,  875, -610,  244,  592,  -28, -206,  538, },
        {  231, -707, -303, -462,  683,  200,   -3, -707,  480,   -2, -920, -743, },
        {  981, -427, -793, -577, -296,  127,  823,  937,  -98, -405,  871, -221, },
        { -139,  841,  299, -415, -773,  403,   92, -474, -384, -219, -636,  -12, },
        {  -89,  -13, -679, -998, -567, -826,  705, -530,  658,  134,  871,  875, },
        { -475, -148, -275,  754,  399, -946,  -78, -469,  655,  -45,   81,  921, },
    };
    enum { MTX1_SIZE = sizeof(mtx1) / sizeof(mtx1[0]) };

    int min[4];
    int max[4];

    matminmax(MTX1_SIZE, mtx1, min, max);
    print_matrix("Matrix 1", MTX1_SIZE, MTX1_SIZE, mtx1);
    print_minmax(min, max);

    /* Created by: gen_matrix -C -H 999 -L -999 -c 13 -r 13 -i -n mtx2 -w 4 */
    /* Random seed: 0xD2A82AC2 */
    const int mtx2[13][13] =
    {
        {  208, -676,  374,  587,  -89, -485, -754,  286, -295, -826, -511, -797,  858, },
        {  991,  423,  404,  477, -449,  442, -860,  629,  437, -606,  974,  522,  885, },
        {  -54, -815, -124,   27,   68, -224,  -95,  430, -244, -941,  857, -843, -306, },
        {   92,  941, -613,  435,  222, -966,   -1,  292, -577,  597,  238,  527, -984, },
        {  978,  661,  315, -347, -747,  242,  711,   15, -922, -623, -533,  794,   65, },
        {  459, -195,  928, -325, -270, -703,   64,  -18, -219,   92,  831, -657,  945, },
        {  250, -102, -861,  -30, -603, -921, -229,  914,  164,  273, -133,  915,  565, },
        {  855, -607,  800, -137,  635, -216, -990, -432, -986, -650,  850,  456,  671, },
        { -393, -159, -685,  537,  598, -680,  241, -799, -821, -750, -559, -164,  103, },
        {  318,  679,  499,  980,  186,  841, -139,  878, -187,  818, -430,  904,  797, },
        { -496,   31, -606,   25, -244,   26, -558, -307, -656,  885,  327, -961, -742, },
        {  558,  592, -562,  148, -543, -995,  534, -519,  257,  784,  982,  508,  470, },
        {  -37,  289,  -94, -513, -115,  -51,  638,  633,   64, -701, -955, -575,  987, },
    };
    enum { MTX2_SIZE = sizeof(mtx2) / sizeof(mtx2[0]) };

    matminmax(MTX2_SIZE, mtx2, min, max);
    print_matrix("Matrix 2", MTX2_SIZE, MTX2_SIZE, mtx2);
    print_minmax(min, max);

    /* Created by: gen_matrix -C -H 999 -L -999 -c 3 -r 3 -i -n mtx3 -w 4 */
    /* Random seed: 0x238E2E67 */
    const int mtx3[3][3] =
    {
        { -703,  420,  896, },
        {  697, -581,  -38, },
        {  829,  878,  722, },
    };
    enum { MTX3_SIZE = sizeof(mtx3) / sizeof(mtx3[0]) };

    matminmax(MTX3_SIZE, mtx3, min, max);
    print_matrix("Matrix 3", MTX3_SIZE, MTX3_SIZE, mtx3);
    print_minmax(min, max);

    /* Created by: gen_matrix -C -H 999 -L -999 -c 4 -r 4 -i -n mtx4 -w 4 */
    /* Random seed: 0x9F26F797 */
    const int mtx4[4][4] =
    {
        { -726,  135,  216,  291, },
        { -628, -901, -594,  313, },
        { -315, -696,  274,  337, },
        {  499,  585, -148, -390, },
    };
    enum { MTX4_SIZE = sizeof(mtx4) / sizeof(mtx4[0]) };

    matminmax(MTX4_SIZE, mtx4, min, max);
    print_matrix("Matrix 4", MTX4_SIZE, MTX4_SIZE, mtx4);
    print_minmax(min, max);

    /* Created by: gen_matrix -C -H 999 -L -999 -c 5 -r 5 -i -n mtx5 -w 4 */
    /* Random seed: 0x10185C02 */
    const int mtx5[5][5] =
    {
        {  -73, -575, -606,  445, -714, },
        {  995, -839, -773,  240,  819, },
        {  132,  581,  956, -495, -914, },
        {  -10, -748,  328, -611, -475, },
        {  249,  249, -839,  152, -408, },
    };
    enum { MTX5_SIZE = sizeof(mtx5) / sizeof(mtx5[0]) };

    matminmax(MTX5_SIZE, mtx5, min, max);
    print_matrix("Matrix 5", MTX5_SIZE, MTX5_SIZE, mtx5);
    print_minmax(min, max);

    /* Created by: gen_matrix -C -H 999 -L -999 -c 6 -r 6 -i -n mtx6 -w 4 */
    /* Random seed: 0x875034FD */
    const int mtx6[6][6] =
    {
        { -814, -712, -938, -333,  123, -626, },
        {  621, -154,  835,  640,  575, -287, },
        { -720, -288, -563,  291,  182, -542, },
        {  132, -954, -404, -859, -796,  212, },
        { -506,  237, -828,  -37,  431,  399, },
        { -943,  151,  567, -414, -902,  959, },
    };
    enum { MTX6_SIZE = sizeof(mtx6) / sizeof(mtx6[0]) };

    matminmax(MTX6_SIZE, mtx6, min, max);
    print_matrix("Matrix 6", MTX6_SIZE, MTX6_SIZE, mtx6);
    print_minmax(min, max);

    /* Created by: gen_matrix -C -H 999 -L -999 -c 7 -r 7 -i -n mtx7 -w 4 */
    /* Random seed: 0x2574C5FF */
    const int mtx7[7][7] =
    {
        {  386, -560,  959, -485,  360,  278, -474, },
        {  440, -360,  617,  214,  -11,  300,  590, },
        { -285,   83, -568,  989, -117, -766,  411, },
        {  944,  598, -568,  414, -596, -882,  640, },
        { -544, -849,  167,  890,  474, -361,   52, },
        {  531,  544, -488,  569,  585, -816,  486, },
        { -542, -965, -758,  590, -314,  401,  964, },
    };
    enum { MTX7_SIZE = sizeof(mtx7) / sizeof(mtx7[0]) };

    matminmax(MTX7_SIZE, mtx7, min, max);
    print_matrix("Matrix 7", MTX7_SIZE, MTX7_SIZE, mtx7);
    print_minmax(min, max);


    return 0;
}

static int max_field_width(size_t n, const int matrix[n][n])
{
    int min_val = matrix[0][0];
    int max_val = matrix[0][0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] < min_val)
                min_val = matrix[i][j];
            if (matrix[i][j] > max_val)
                max_val = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    int fld_width = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", max_val);
    if (min_val < 0)
    {
        int min_width = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", min_val);
        if (min_width > fld_width)
            fld_width = min_width;
    }
    return fld_width;
}

static void print_matrix(const char *tag, size_t n, size_t m, const int matrix[n][m])
{
    printf("%s (%zux%zu):\n", tag, n, m);
    int w = max_field_width(n, matrix) + 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%*d", w, matrix[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Matrix 1 (12x12):
  688  351 -309 -491 -200  958 -699 -284 -638  696 -427   43
 -621  242  913 -247 -293  878  538  368 -861  488 -568  394
 -646 -813 -943 -417 -697  551  325   11 -234   18  348 -229
  436  529 -994  457 -270  369  318 -455 -918  444 -821  266
  544   24  398 -589 -779   -2  932  810 -915 -591  877  865
   19  879 -528 -483  961  478 -426  528  522 -403 -859  -63
  830  103 -662 -894  -29  875 -610  244  592  -28 -206  538
  231 -707 -303 -462  683  200   -3 -707  480   -2 -920 -743
  981 -427 -793 -577 -296  127  823  937  -98 -405  871 -221
 -139  841  299 -415 -773  403   92 -474 -384 -219 -636  -12
  -89  -13 -679 -998 -567 -826  705 -530  658  134  871  875
 -475 -148 -275  754  399 -946  -78 -469  655  -45   81  921

N quadrant: min = -861, max =  958
W quadrant: min = -994, max =  981
E quadrant: min = -920, max =  877
S quadrant: min = -998, max =  937

Matrix 2 (13x13):
  208 -676  374  587  -89 -485 -754  286 -295 -826 -511 -797  858
  991  423  404  477 -449  442 -860  629  437 -606  974  522  885
  -54 -815 -124   27   68 -224  -95  430 -244 -941  857 -843 -306
   92  941 -613  435  222 -966   -1  292 -577  597  238  527 -984
  978  661  315 -347 -747  242  711   15 -922 -623 -533  794   65
  459 -195  928 -325 -270 -703   64  -18 -219   92  831 -657  945
  250 -102 -861  -30 -603 -921 -229  914  164  273 -133  915  565
  855 -607  800 -137  635 -216 -990 -432 -986 -650  850  456  671
 -393 -159 -685  537  598 -680  241 -799 -821 -750 -559 -164  103
  318  679  499  980  186  841 -139  878 -187  818 -430  904  797
 -496   31 -606   25 -244   26 -558 -307 -656  885  327 -961 -742
  558  592 -562  148 -543 -995  534 -519  257  784  982  508  470
  -37  289  -94 -513 -115  -51  638  633   64 -701 -955 -575  987

N quadrant: min = -966, max =  974
W quadrant: min = -921, max =  991
E quadrant: min = -986, max =  945
S quadrant: min = -995, max =  982

Matrix 3 (3x3):
 -703  420  896
  697 -581  -38
  829  878  722

N quadrant: min =  420, max =  420
W quadrant: min =  697, max =  697
E quadrant: min =  -38, max =  -38
S quadrant: min =  878, max =  878

Matrix 4 (4x4):
 -726  135  216  291
 -628 -901 -594  313
 -315 -696  274  337
  499  585 -148 -390

N quadrant: min =  135, max =  216
W quadrant: min = -628, max = -315
E quadrant: min =  313, max =  337
S quadrant: min = -148, max =  585

Matrix 5 (5x5):
  -73 -575 -606  445 -714
  995 -839 -773  240  819
  132  581  956 -495 -914
  -10 -748  328 -611 -475
  249  249 -839  152 -408

N quadrant: min = -773, max =  445
W quadrant: min =  -10, max =  995
E quadrant: min = -914, max =  819
S quadrant: min = -839, max =  328

Matrix 6 (6x6):
 -814 -712 -938 -333  123 -626
  621 -154  835  640  575 -287
 -720 -288 -563  291  182 -542
  132 -954 -404 -859 -796  212
 -506  237 -828  -37  431  399
 -943  151  567 -414 -902  959

N quadrant: min = -938, max =  835
W quadrant: min = -954, max =  621
E quadrant: min = -796, max =  399
S quadrant: min = -902, max =  567

Matrix 7 (7x7):
  386 -560  959 -485  360  278 -474
  440 -360  617  214  -11  300  590
 -285   83 -568  989 -117 -766  411
  944  598 -568  414 -596 -882  640
 -544 -849  167  890  474 -361   52
  531  544 -488  569  585 -816  486
 -542 -965 -758  590 -314  401  964

N quadrant: min = -560, max =  989
W quadrant: min = -849, max =  944
E quadrant: min = -882, max =  640
S quadrant: min = -965, max =  890
```

Comment: could you translate your int quadrant function into standard code, it's hard readable for me?

Comment: It is standard C code — it uses simple conditions, the ternary operator (twice), and simple numbers.  I don't think it can be made much simpler.  It could be made more convoluted.  For example, `int quadrant = (r > c) + 2 * (r + c > N - 1);` — which uses the property that a condition such as `(r > c)` evaluates to 0 if it is false or 1 if it is true.  I suppose you could write `if (r < c) { if (r + c < N - 1) quadrant = 0; else quadrant = 2; } else if (r + c < N - 1) quadrant = 1; else quadrant = 3;` or something similar, but it isn't exactly clearer and involves unnecessary duplication.

Comment: I have tried this and it works for maximum elements, however for minimal it works only for N area. Could you find what's wrong here:  https://onlinegdb.com/m4YaxvFBm

Comment: You have `double min[10]={100},max[10]={0};;` — The second semicolon is superfluous; you initialized `max` to all values `0`, but you only initialized `min[0]` to 100; the rest are also 0. Your code is not robust for all possible inputs. You should initialize the `min` and `max` elements to values from the appropriate quadrant: `min[QW] = max[QW] = mat[1][0]; min[QN] = max[QN] = mat[1][0]; min[QS] = max[QS] = mat[N-1][1]; min[QE] = max[QE] = mat[1][N-1];`. The `Qx` tokens indicate which quadrant is which; `N` is the size of the array.

Comment: I also observe that there are only 4 quadrants, so using `10` for the array dimension is a little excessive.  It's not a serious memory hog, but it is reserving unnecessary and unused memory.

Comment: I think first values for N and W should have index [0][1]

Comment: Yes; I mistyped the assignment for QN in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858579/find-maximum-and-minimum-nondiagonal-elements-of-matrix/70858903?noredirect=1#comment125268183_70858903); it should be `min[QN] = max[QN] = mat[0][1];` — my bad!